# How does Map marge works?

Tags: dart

Can anybody tell me what does below code does . I am literally lost out the procedure the code does

```
Map<String, dynamic> deepMerge(Map<String, dynamic> toMerge) {
    var source = <String, dynamic>{...this};
    for (var key in toMerge.keys) {
      if (source.containsKey(key) && source[key] is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        if (toMerge[key] is Map<String, dynamic>) {
          source[key] = (source[key] as Map<String, dynamic>).deepMerge(toMerge[key]);
        }
      } else {
        source[key] = toMerge[key];
      }
    }
    return source;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It recursively traverses a structure of (likely JSON) maps and adds values to it from a parallel structure.

The function is very likely an extension method on `Map<String, dynamic>`, so `this` refers to such a map, and so does `toMerge`.

It starts by creating a copy of `this` map, and then goes through all the entries of `toMerge` and adds them to the copy as well.

However, if the value of a key in "this" map is itself a *map*, then it doesn't overwrite that value by the `toMerge` value. Instead, if the `toMerge` value of the same key is also a map, it recursively creates a deep copy and merge of those two maps, and uses that value instead.
If not, it keeps the current map and ignores the value from `toMerge` (which is, arguably, slightly inconsistent, but for structured JSON data, it'll probably never happen).